# VMware Tools Installation on Ubuntu 10

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

When i'm trying to Install VMware tools on my UBUNTU 10 virtual machine on VMware Workstation . VM -> Install Vmware Tools , I am geting the follow error popup.

The VirtualMachine needs to have a virtual CD/DVD device to install VMware tools.

Please help me how to install it manually .

Comment: First, this question is off topic for SO, it is more suited for [su]. That being said, mount the .iso containing the VMware Tools in your host system (you'll find the location of the iso in the documentation of VMware Workstation), copy it over to the VM with any method that suits you and begin with the installation. Alternatively you can just use the open-vm-tools that come with Ubuntu, they are less troublesome anyway in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

This is for VMWare Workstation.

First go into Settings for that VM and make sure you have a CD/DVD drive configured. That is your error. If you don't see one in the Hardware tab, then choose the "Add" button and add a CD/DVD device.

Then:

In the menu options, choose VM -> Reinstall VMware Tools. That will mount the iso. Once file manager opens you can uncompress the tar.gz file and CD to that location. Once in the correct location you use the following command to install.

```
xyzubuntu~$ sudo vmware-install.pl
```

That will reinstall VMWare tools

Answer (score 0):

You can install VmWare-tools manually:

- Unmount CD images if any
- Mount VMwareTools CD image manualy:
  The file is:

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\linux.iso`

  You can find it in your system if VMware Workstation installed correctly.
- Open CD image and untar VMwareTools-9.9.2-2496486.tar.gz
- Install with command line:

  `cd vmware-tools-distrib
  sudo vmware-install.pl`

  After that restart your VM. done.